# CSS's @font-face local() won't locate other font styles than "regular" and "bold"

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, local

So... I installed some fonts (Roboto) on my PC (linux ubuntu) and I want to use them in my CSS using `@font-face`, but when I defined those `local()` inside of `src: ;` like this for eg. ->

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url('Roboto.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

.

### Problem:

Only font styles/weights that work are - `font-weight: 400` (**regular**) and `font-weight: 600` (**bold**), but when I change it to `font-weight: 500` (**medium**) or any other, it just **doesn't change!**

.

### Things I tried to fix the problem:

**1)** Defining another `@font-face`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url('Roboto-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

**Result:** Console error: `Failed to decode downloaded font: pathToMySite/css/Roboto-Medium.ttf` and it just stays the same (*regular*)

**2)** I tried to list all fonts, to see if those fonts are actually installed (using linux command: `fc-list | grep "Roboto"` which just outputs all locally installed fonts (that has "Roboto" in them)

**Output**:

```
lots/of/paths/Roboto-Regular.ttf: Roboto:style=Regular
lots/of/paths/Roboto-Italic.ttf: Roboto:style=Italic
lots/of/paths/Roboto-Medium.ttf: Roboto Medium:style=Regular
lots/of/paths/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf: Roboto Medium:style=Italic
lots/of/paths/Roboto-Bold.ttf: Roboto:style=Bold
lots/of/paths/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf: Roboto:style=Bold Italic
lots/of/paths/Roboto-Light.ttf: Roboto Light:style=Regular
lots/of/paths/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf: Roboto Light:style=Italic
lots/of/paths/Roboto-Thin.ttf: Roboto Thin:style=Regular
lots/of/paths/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf: Roboto Thin:style=Italic
```

(there were even more paths to different folders, but file names were always the same)

**3)** I tried to go to linux "fonts" app, to see if those fonts are actually installed.

**All Roboto variations** (thin, light, regular, medium, bold, black) **were there** and **visibly different** (in case *medium* and *regular* looked the same)

**4)** And yes I refreshed it using `CTRL + F5` and yes I have `cache` disabled.

**Long story short:** all fonts are installed on the system, but CSS just doesn't see anything other than **regular** and **bold** weight or can't locate them? Or I don't know why.

**Can you help me solve this?** Thank you for your help!

Comment: Protip: if you actually care about your typography enough to use a `@font-face` rule, don't use `local`. You wanted control over the font, so don't then go "or, whatever you have installed that happens to have the same name, I don't care". You care: _enforce_ the exact font =) As for the error: [don't use `ttf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462040/csss-font-face-local-wont-locate-other-font-styles-than-regular-and-bold). Get the .woff source for Roboto, and then use that, and only that.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use local, just url, as:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'Regular'; src: url('fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'); }
@font-face {font-family: 'Light'; src: url('fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf'); }
@font-face {font-family: 'Medium'; src: url('fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'); }
@font-face {font-family: 'Bold'; src: url('fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf'); }
```

CSS:

```
.my_div{
   font-family: Light;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and after some try I find out a pretty simple solution that worked for me.

1. Define the **custom font**, this will be downloaded and used if the font is not installed

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'RobotoDL';
  src: url('path/to/Roboto-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('path/to/Roboto-Medium.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}
// Define it for each font-weight and font-style
```

2. Define the font-family using the **installed font** name as first option and the **custom font** name as fallback, for example

```
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'RobotoDL', Arial,  sans-serif;
  // font-name installed, font-name custom, standard fallbacks
}
```

In this way:

- If the user **does** have the font installed than the browser will use **'Roboto'** and it won't download anything.
- If the user **doesn't** have the font installed, the browser will use **'RobotoDL'** and it will download the files described by the font-face rules.

---

I read online that using the font-family property like this

```
font-family: 'installed font name', fallbacks, etc;
```

doesn't get the installed font and will instead get the fallbacks. In my case it does get the installed font (without any download), so I don't know for sure if this solution will works or there's something that I have missed, but I'd give it a try.